# issue with code could not run in Pine Script? “Undeclared identifier” error

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, binance

Every time I tried to run the code I got this message.

```
10:32:09 PM Error at 4:37 Undeclared identifier 'input.'
10:32:09 PM Error at 4:32 The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'type'
10:32:09 PM Error at 6:5 Could not find function or function reference 'highest'
```

this is the full code

```
"//@version=5
indicator("Flag Pattern", shorttitle="Flag Pattern", overlay=true)

length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=10)

h = highest(high, length)
l = lowest(low, length)
price_range = h - l

flag_height = price_range * 2
flag_width = rma(tr, length) * 2

flagpole_start_x = length - 1
flagpole_start_y = l
flagpole_end_x = length - 1
flagpole_end_y = h

flag_start_x = flagpole_end_x + 1
flag_start_y = flagpole_end_y
flag_end_x = flag_start_x + flag_width
flag_end_y = flag_start_y + flag_height

line.new(x1=flagpole_start_x, y1=flagpole_start_y, x2=flagpole_end_x, y2=flagpole_end_y, color=color.white, width=1)
linebr = line.new(x1=flag_start_x, y1=flag_start_y, x2=flag_end_x, y2=flag_end_y, color=color.white, width=1)
line.new(x1=flag_start_x, y1=flagpole_start_y, x2=flagpole_end_x, y2=flagpole_start_y, color=color.white, width=1)
line.new(x1=flag_end_x, y1=flagpole_end_y, x2=flagpole_end_x, y2=flag_start_y, color=color.white, width=1)

flag_high = valuewhen(crossunder(low, l, 1), high, 0)
flag_low = valuewhen(crossover(high, h, 1), low, 0)

is_flag = flag_high > 0 and flag_low > 0 and flag_high > flag_low and flag_high - flag_low > price_range

bgcolor(is_flag ? color.green : na, transp=80)"
```

how to find out what the issue is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This code is written in `v4` and not in `v5`.

So, change your `indicator()` call to `study()`.

You are also passing a `float` to your `line.new()`'s `x1` and `x2` arguments which will not work. You may try casting them to int with `int()`.

Lastly, your use of `crossover()` and `crossunder()` are wrong. Those functions take two parameters.

```
crossover(x, y) → series[bool]
```

> **RETURNS** 
> true if `x` crossed over `y` otherwise false
> **ARGUMENTS**
> ***x (float)*** Data series `x`.
> ***y (float)*** Data series `y`.